# Getting around label click property

Tags: html, css

I'm using labels for a form. When you click on a "line" of a label, this will select the input for you, which is natural.

However, when I wanted to use, for example, 3 selects within the same `<label>` (DD/MM/YY), it won't select none, probably given that there should only be one input.

Is there any way to make it so labels won't automatically focus on an input, or should I pick another way to place the selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the ID of the label same as the first field of the date input. For example see the demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/E4Fh5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the convention in this case is to assign the label to the *first* select element.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

> for = idref [CS] This attribute
>   explicitly associates the label being
>   defined with another control. When
>   present, the value of this attribute
>   must be the same as the value of the
>   id attribute of some other control in
>   the same document. When absent, the
>   label being defined is associated with
>   the element's contents.

I'm assuming you currently have the `<select>` inside of the `<label>`.

If you move the content outside without setting the `for` attribute, it should do what your're after:

`<label>Date<label><select></select>...`

Answer (score 0):

For accessibility of screen readers, you should actually have 3 labels here, one for each select, but you probably only want the first one to be visible and as Tobias said, assigned to the first select.